# EasyAdmin 3 : Nested forms (Callection in another Collection)

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin3

I use EasyAdmin 3.

I'm creating a newsletter manager with Symfony 5. My entities are built as such.

- Newsletter `(ManyToOne => NewsletterItem)`

  - NewsletterItem `(ManyToOne => NewsletteItemSub)`

    - NewsletteItemSub

In EasyAdmin, I was able to add a NewsletterItem in Newsletter. But I don't know how to add a NewsletterItemSub in NewsletterItem in EasyAdmin.

Does anyone have an idea?

My current code :

```
CollectionField::new('newsletterItems', 'Newsletter Items')
     ->allowAdd()
     ->allowAdd()
     ->setEntryIsComplex(false)
     ->setEntryType(NewsletterItemType::class)
     ->showEntryLabel(false)
     ->setFormTypeOptions([
         by_reference' => false
        ]
     )
     ->hideOnIndex(),
```

[image: What I have now.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create NewsletteItemSubType form class and embed it in NewsletterItemType

Something like this:

```
<?php
#...
class NewsletterItemType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        #...

        $builder->add('tags', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => NewsletteItemSubType::class,
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
        ]);
    }

    #...
}
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Thanks, I had already found it. It works perfectly.